# What am I doing wrong when sending a request? x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, resttemplate

When sending request with Postman, the response returns successful. But when I send it with spring resttemplate, I get the following error

"httpCode": "400",
"httpMessage": "Bad Request",
"moreInformation": "One or more required API parameters are missing in the API request."

Content-Type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept = application/json

This is my Code:

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

    String clientConf = clientId + ":" +clientSecret;
    String base64ClientConf = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(clientConf.getBytes());
    headers.set("Authorization","Basic "+ base64ClientConf);

    MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    map.add("grant_type",this.grantType);
    map.add("scope",this.scopes);
    map.add("username",this.username);
    map.add("password",this.password);
    map.add("client_id",this.clientId);
    map.add("client_secret",this.clientSecret);


    URI uri = URI.create("url");
    HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity<>(map,headers);

    try {
        ResponseEntity<TokenResponse> queryResponseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(uri.toString(), HttpMethod.POST,entity, TokenResponse.class);
        TokenResponse queryResponses = queryResponseEntity.getBody();
        System.out.println(queryResponses);
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException | HttpServerErrorException httpClientOrServerExc) {
        System.out.println("RestTemplate response Code =  " + httpClientOrServerExc.getStatusCode() + " Hata = " + httpClientOrServerExc.getMessage());
        throw new Exception("RestTemplate response Code =  " + httpClientOrServerExc.getStatusCode() + " Hata = " + httpClientOrServerExc.getMessage());
    }
```

This postman request Body:

[image]

This postman request header:

[image]

I think the request body is not going, but as a result of my researches, this is how the SpringResttemplate library is sent. If there is something I missed, I would appreciate it if you could help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use restTemplate, you need to add custom converter. If you don't have to use you can use also other libraries like OkHttp.

If you need to use restTemplate. It need to be like code below;

```
 List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
 MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new 
 MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
 converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.ALL));
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 messageConverters.add(new ObjectToUrlEncodedConverter(mapper));
 messageConverters.add(converter);
 restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
```

We need to be careful about converter order if we need to pass request object. Firstly add `ObjectToUrlEncodedConverter` and add `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` by order.

`ObjectToUrlEncodedConverter` it should be like:

```
public class ObjectToUrlEncodedMapper implements 
HttpMessageConverter {

private static final String ENCODING = "UTF-8";

private final ObjectMapper mapper;

public ObjectToUrlEncodedMapper(ObjectMapper mapper) {
    this.mapper = mapper;
}

@Override
public boolean canRead(Class clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean canWrite(Class clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
    return getSupportedMediaTypes().contains(mediaType);
}

@Override
public List<MediaType> getSupportedMediaTypes() {
    return Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
}

@Override
public Object read(Class clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws HttpMessageNotReadableException {
    throw new RuntimeException();
}

@Override
public void write(Object o, MediaType contentType, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws HttpMessageNotWritableException {
    if (o != null) {
        String body = mapper
                .convertValue(o, UrlEncodedWriter.class)
                .toString();

        try {
            outputMessage.getBody().write(body.getBytes(ENCODING));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // if UTF-8 is not supporter then I give up
        }
    }
}

private static class UrlEncodedWriter {
    private final StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void write(String name, Object property) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        if (out.length() > 0) {
            out.append("&");
        }

        out
                .append(URLEncoder.encode(name, ENCODING))
                .append("=");

        if (property != null) {
            out.append(URLEncoder.encode(property.toString(), ENCODING));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return out.toString();
    }
}
```